# Run and clear different programs in python and clear the console and variables

Tags: python, console, python-import

I am working with Spyder. I have 50 codes called `node1.py` to `node50.py` I want to do this more efficiently than just loading each file manually and pressing the run key.

I have found [this tutorial](https://datatofish.com/one-python-script-from-another/) and built a code in which I import the 50 files as `import node3.py`. However, I would like to close the console after each run to clear all tehe variables. Unfortunately, I don't see anywhere how to do this from a script. Can anyone please tell me what I have to introduce to close the console or clear all what I have introduced?

Comment: If you follow the tutorial and do `from node1 import x` then `x` is a part of your controller program's namespace, which is why you get leftovers moving from `node1` to `node2`. Don't use `from ... import ...`. Instead, simply do `import node1` and `import node2`. Then `node1.x` is a different variable from `node2.x` and there is no need to clear them in between.